# (Python) changing csv file into list of tuples

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

If I use this code:

```py
    with open('data/stock.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

The result is:

```
['2020-07-01', 'NYSE', 'Johnson & Johnson', 'JNJ', '140.38', '6174800']
['2020-07-02', 'NASDAQ', 'Apple Inc.', 'AAPL', '91.03', '114041600']
['2020-07-02', 'NASDAQ', 'Microsoft Corporation', 'MSFT', '206.26', '29315800']
['2020-07-02', 'NYSE', 'Berkshire Hathaway Inc.', 'BRK', '267551', '500']
...
```

With this rows, What i have to do is changing this result to:

```
stock_tuples = [('2020-07-01', 'NYSE', 'Johnson & Johnson', 'JNJ', 140.38, 6174800), ('2020-07-02', 'NASDAQ', 'Apple Inc.', 'AAPL', 91.03, 114041600), ....]
```

Which means,

- I have to change each **rows' type** as *str, str, str, str, float, int*
- I have to make the rows in **one list of tuples**.

**Caution**: I cannot import any other things except `import csv`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have to change rows into list of tuples named stock_tuples.

Comment: you can refer [here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/oOzKXyNV) for full code

Answer (score 0):

Try *list comprehension*,
so instead of:

```py
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

**use the following:**

```py
stock_tuples = [tuple(row) for row in reader]
```

Then you'll have the required result in the `stock_tuples` variable.